# HBase, Hadoop : How can I estimate the size of a HBase table or Hadoop File System Paths?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have multiple HBase tables, how can I estimate the approximate size of the tables using in java?

Comment: here you can use https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html for printing size of hdfs (hbase ) folder size in human readable format. please check last method in the `HDFSUtil` given in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is you have to access hdfs using java client usually under `/hbase` folder
all the tables info. will be present.

#### Hadoop shell :

you can check that using `hadoop fs -du -h **path to hbase**/hbase`

under /hbase each table occupies one more folder...

`hadoop fs  -ls -R **path to hbase**/hbase`

`hadoop fs -du -h **path to hbase**/hbase/tablename`

#### Java HDFS Client :

Same thing you can use java hdfs client by passing each table path under hbase root dir like below ...
Check `getSizeOfPaths` & `getSizeOfDirectory` methods

```
public class HdfsUtil {
    /**
     * Estimates the number of splits by taking the size of the paths and dividing by the splitSize.
     *
     * @param paths
     * @param configuration
     * @param splitSize
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static long getNumOfSplitsForInputs(Path[] paths, Configuration configuration, long splitSize) throws IOException
    {
        long size = getSizeOfPaths(paths, configuration);
        long splits = (int) Math.ceil( size / (splitSize)) ;
        return splits;
    }

    public static long getSizeOfPaths(Path[] paths, Configuration configuration) throws IOException
    {
        long totalSize = 0L;

        for(Path path: paths)
        {
           totalSize += getSizeOfDirectory(path, configuration);
        }
        return totalSize;
    }
// here you can give hbase path folder which was described through shell
        public static long getSizeOfDirectory(Path path, Configuration configuration) throws IOException {
            //Get the file size of the unannotated Edges
            FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(configuration);
            long size  = fileSystem.getContentSummary(path).getLength();
/**static String    byteCountToDisplaySize(BigInteger size)
Returns a human-readable version of the file size, where the input represents a specific number of bytes.**/
System.out.println(FileUtils.byteCountToDisplaySize(size))
            return size;
        }
    }
```