# Deleting cells of a row in HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nosql

I am new to HBase and I am creating a large table. My table periodically is being scanned and some data related to some row are being deleted.

I wanted to know if for a specific row , I delete some columns of that row, it decrease the amount of disk consumption so it reduces the amount of disk being used?

Comment: Was it useful? Feel free to ask questions...

Answer (score 0):

Hbase data will be stored in HDFS usally under `/hbase`

Obviously, it will reduce some space if you delete data.

please check like below

#### Precheck :

```
hadoop fs -ls -R yourpath to hbase usally /hbase

hadoop fs -du -h yourpath to hbase usally /hbase
```

#### Delete : now you run your program to delete...

#### PostCheck :

```
 hadoop fs -du -h yourpath to hbase usally /hbase
```

**Note :** you can remove `-h` option if you want to observe minute size change in bytes.

- `-h` is human readable size i.e in mbs , GB with this minute difference cant be observed.

#### Please see my answer [if you want to do it programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40726939/647053)

Comment: if you are okay! pls care to vote-up/accept answer as owner. Thanks